# How to include new line in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a php script that reads a text file. This text file looks like this.

```
09/27/17 
3:00p  
sam1, 
sam  
15 
(999) 
999-9999
M:(888) 
888-8888 
17  
09/27/17  
3:30p   
mark1, 
marke  
asd
15 
(777) 
777-7777 
M:(666) 
666-6666 
17
```

What I need to do is extract the phone number but the problem is the phone number is splitted in two line as you see so

**My PHP script:**

```
    $string = ""; 
    $date=array();
    $data1 = file("data.txt"); 
    for($i =0; $i < count($data1);$i++)
 { 
    $data = explode(" ",$data1[$i]); 
    $line = $data[0]; 
    //$string .=$line; 

    if (preg_match('^[M:]\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/s^',$line)) {
        $string .= $line."\n"; 
    }

    if (preg_match('^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/s^',$line)) {
        $string .= $line."\n"; 
    }

 }
```

**I need it to be like so:**

```
   (999)999-9999,M:(888)888-8888  
   (777)777-7777,M:(666)666-6666
```

but I am not getting any result because the regex is not valid

**What is the correct regex to achieve this?** thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex. The required mobile number can be formed by concatenating what is present in Group1 and Group2 of each of these matches.

```
^((?:M:)?\(\d{3}\))\s*(\d{3}-\d{4})
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4mU8kv/2)

**Explanation:**

- `((?:M:)?\(\d{3}\))` - Capturing group 1

  - `(?:M:)?` - Matches 0 or 1 occurrences of the letter `M`
  - `\(` - matches `(` literally
  - `\d{3}` - matches 3 digits
  - `\)` - matches `)` literally
- `\s*` - matches 0 or more white space characters
- `(\d{3}-\d{4})` - 2nd Capturing group containing the sequence of 3 digits followed by a `-` followed by another 4 digits

**[Click here to see the Code and Output](http://tpcg.io/uu0wwS)**

[image]

Comment: (+1) but consider using anchors as well, it reduces the steps needed dramatically: **https://regex101.com/r/4mU8kv/2**

Comment: Updated. You are correct. The no. of steps were less when I used the `^` anchor.

Comment: thanks its works ,but  some time the phone number appear like this (999) how can i add something to the regex to catch it and print it?

Comment: (999)? A 3-digit phone number? Could you pls give an example?

Comment: like this :09/27/17 
3:00p  
sam1, 
sam  
15 
(999) 
17  
09/27/17  
3:30p   
mark1,

Comment: @ajack See [here](https://regex101.com/r/4mU8kv/3). The output you get is `(999)`.

Comment: but now i have another problem can help with it please ? i will appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155661/discussion-between-gurman-and-ajack).